# iptables owner match drops icmp for GIDs but not for UIDs

Tags: iptables, icmp, user-permissions

I have a strange behaviour of `iptables` that I cannot explain or understand.

I have a user `test` which has its primary group `test`. I want to block any network access from this user.

Now, if I say

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m owner --uid-owner test -j DROP
```

and I `su test` and then I get the following:

```
ping serverfault.com       # WORKS
nmap -sP serverfault.com   # fails
wget serverfault.com       # fails
```

However, if I flush the iptables again, and say instead:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m owner --gid-owner test -j DROP
```

(notice the difference: `gid` instead of `uid`) then I get the following

```
ping serverfault.com       # fails
nmap -sP serverfault.com   # fails
wget serverfault.com       # fails
```

So as you can see, the rule seems to match both times, but only when I block the primary group also ICMP is blocked.
Is this a bug or does this make some sense that I am unaware of?

I mean I could simply block both and be happy, but I want to understand why they behave differently.

My `iptables` version is `v1.4.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generation of icmp requires raw access to a socket which in turn requires root access.  Ping therefore runs suid, so the uid for the owner of the socket is root and not test.

Comment: Ah! That actually makes a lot of sense, thank you.